# Is there a function implement reverse memmem in C or C++ ？

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, function

I want to find "\r\n\r\n" in a HTTP header.
I know it's at the end of the packet, so if I reverse search "\r\n\r\n" I'll get good performance.

Is there a  function implement reverse search in C or C++ ?
If so, which one?
Thanks.

Comment: An HTTP message is not divided into "packets". It's just a stream of bytes. The HTTP body will immediately follow the HTTP header, and can certainly contain "\r\n\r\n" in the body. I recommend searching *forward* through the headers, not backwards, because if you search backwards you don't know where to start looking.

Comment: @GregHewgill great answer.  Since you need to scan forwards to find the end of the header anyway, it's more efficient to pick it up on the forward pass.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reverse searching for "\r\n\r\n" might give you wrong result. It is not correct logic, because the HTTP body might contain "\r\n\r\n".

Answer (score 1):

In C++, many of the containers offer `rbegin()` and `rend()`, which implement iteration in reverse. You could then hand these to any of the standard algorithms.

For example, [`std::string::rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) and [`std::string::rend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do this to solve your problem is incorrect; if you already know the length of the header, then there's no search to be done for the `\r\n\r\n`; it's located at the `n-4` position where `n` is the length. If you don't know the length, then computing the length starting from the beginning takes just as long as searching for the `\r\n\r\n`.

With that said, the question of how to do a "reverse" `strstr` or `memmem` is valid. For `strstr`, the optimal method is simply repeatedly calling the forward `strstr`, using the previous match plus one character at a starting point, and keeping the last occurrance found. For `memmem`, you could attain much greater performance by adapting the optimal forward algorithm to run in reverse (basically just negating all the indices).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

Assuming `header` is a `std::string`:

```
header.rfind( "\r\n\r\n" );
```

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky I absolutely did.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is - `std::find_end`. Used like so:

```
string  str = "abcabc";
string  substr = "abc";     

string::iterator ret = 
  std::find_end(str.begin(), str.end(), substr.begin(), substr.end());

if (ret == str.end())  cout << "not found\n";
else                   cout << "at: " << result - str.begin() << "\n";
```

Also if you are searching in `std::string` there is `std::string::rfind()` method. `std::find_end()` is good for any container, including `char[]`